# Presence of certain cookies restrict me from accessing websites

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cookies

I have a problem on a refurbished computer that I haven't use in a long time (Windows 10).

First time I booted it after the refurbish it worked as intended. Since then, anytime I try to access a website from a browser, I get an error:

This Page isn't Working

[www.website.com](http://www.website.com) didn't send any data.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

If I expend this error message I see:

Your connection to this site is not secure.

I played around with the settings to try and find the origin of the problem. I found out that clearing all caches & cookies would allow me to have access to the websites again, but only once (the error message would reappear on reloads). Digging deeper I found out that the cookies were the origin of the problem. If I clear all cookies, my browser is able to access the website with no problem (but again, only once, since accessing the website means creating the same cookies over again).

I gradually deleted some cookies to see if I could find a pattern. I found out that some cookies cause no problem while others seem to be the origin of the error messages. I fail to see any logic behind why some would work and why some would make my browsers crash. They do not have specific features to differentiate between them.

I have tried this on Edge & Chrome, both with the same effect.

If anybody has an intuition as to why this error happens, this would help me a lot.

Thank you!

Comment: have you walked through the troubleshooting steps here: https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-fix-an-err_empty_response-error-in-google-chrome/ ? how many sites does this occur on? just one? are you specifing HTTPS in the URL?

Comment: Have you used the Network troubleshooter? Have you tried a better browser, like Firefox?

Comment: Check for both http and https links.